# vim: map a key to entering a mapping command

Tags: vim

In vim I'd like to use a hotkey to enter a mapping command, which in turn maps a hotkey to a string of commands. Here's what I'm doing:

```
nnoremap <leader>r :map `t :w<cr>:silent !make<cr>:redraw!<cr>
```

As you can see, when I press `<leader>r`, vim will put the mapping command on the command line and I can modify the actual command (in this case `make`) then create the mapping by pressing enter.

Now, this doesn't really work because the `<cr>`s will apply to the `nnoremap` command. How do I escape those and have them show up on the command line so they apply to the `:map` command?

Comment: The fact that I needed to use so many escape sequences to ask a question about escape sequences is just mind-blowing. And how meta is this comment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To add `<...>` literally to a mapping you need to escape the file `<` with `<lt>`. So `<cr>` would become `<lt>cr>`.

So your mapping would look like

```
nnoremap <leader>r :map `t :w<lt>cr>:silent !make<lt>cr>:redraw!<lt>cr>
```

---

This is covered in the help as a subsection to `:h command-bang`

```
Replacement text

The replacement text for a user defined command is scanned for special escape
sequences, using <...> notation.  Escape sequences are replaced with values
from the entered command line, and all other text is copied unchanged.  The
resulting string is executed as an Ex command.  To avoid the replacement use
<lt> in place of the initial <.  Thus to include "<bang>" literally use
"<lt>bang>".
```